# Java: Random permutation without importing java.util

Tags: java, permutation, shuffle, knuth

There are many different instructions to do random permutation on the Internet, but they all use libraries. Is there any way to do random permutation **without using any built-in library**? I know how to generate random numbers using `Math.random()`. Does generating random permutation have to do with `Math.random()`? Shuffling looks so complicated to me.

My goal is if I run the programme by 'java randompermutation 3', then the programme returns either 1,2,3 or 1,3,2, or 3,1,2, or 3,2,1, or 2,3,1, or 2,1,3

Comment: what is *the simple way* from your point of view?

Comment: If you don't use any library, you would still end up implementing probably the same algorithm used by library, which doesn't make sense unless you want to learn the algorithm itself. So, again, what do you mean by simple here ?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: See my proof using backtrack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58314302/10910098).

Comment: @ adzo261 I meant 'a straightforward way to do it'

Comment: *"Is there any way to do random permutation without using any in-built library?"* Yes, that means you need a shuffling algorithm. *"Shuffling looks so complicated to me."* I see, so you need to do X but you don't want to do X. It's a direct contradiction.

Comment: "I know how to generate random numbers using Math.random()" - that _is_ using an in-built library already.

Comment: @ daniu I meant to say that I didn't want to import something like this import java.util

Comment: What's wrong with importing? I'm not trying to be annoying, I'm just curious.

Comment: @studenthahahoho java.util is a standard java library, it is not an external library. It sounds like you don't want to use java's features. To me, this sounds like saying "how can I get the rain off my car's windshield, without using the car's wipers?"

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like the example shown below

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Integer[] input = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        Integer[] shuffleInput = shuffle(input);

        for (int i=0; i<shuffleInput.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(shuffleInput[i]);
        }
    }

    public static Integer[] shuffle(Integer[] input) {
        Integer[] inputCopy = input.clone();;
        Integer[] output = new Integer[input.length];

        for (int i=0; i<output.length; i++) {
            // Find and get a random element
            int randPicker = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() % inputCopy.length);
            output[i] = inputCopy[randPicker];

            // Remove selected element from copy
            Integer[] aux = new Integer[inputCopy.length - 1];
            System.arraycopy(inputCopy, 0, aux, 0, randPicker);
            if (inputCopy.length != randPicker) {
                System.arraycopy(inputCopy, randPicker + 1, aux, randPicker, inputCopy.length - randPicker - 1);
            }
            inputCopy = aux;
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

This code takes a list of `Integer` of any size as input, and return a list with the mixed values.

If the list will always be 3 numbers, it could be a simpler version.

**EDITED:** This version does not use `Math.random()` or any other `java.util`.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I meant to say that I didn't want to use java.util

Comment: Try this new version without any java.util. you can always check the implementation of a method and copy it directly.

Answer (score 0):

One algorithm for sorting an array is based on selection sort and is called selection shuffle. Go through the array and for each index, pick a random index following it and swap those two indices. Since this looks a bit like homework, I will refrain from giving any actual code, but this is a solution.